# Cell vertical top alignment using poi

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am using POI api. Now my problem is that I am not able to align cell text vertically top.I am using `getCellStyle().setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP)` to set alignment .

Yet when I open sheet it is not impacted.

Answer (score 29):

Had this problem as well, you will be supprised but to set vertical aligment  to style in POI you should use **`setVerticalAlignment()`** function not `setAlignment()`. Example:

```
XSSFCellStyle styleSubHeader = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
styleSubHeader.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code :

```
style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
```

Answer (score 9):

this implementation

```
style.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP)
```

is deprecated, use :

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
XSSFWorkbook wbOut = new XSSFWorkbook();    
CellStyle style = wbOut.createCellStyle();
style.setVerticalAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cell = row.createCell((short) 2);
cell.setCellValue("X");
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```